# Data in pipe separated format insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I wrote a function which returns a table with single column with data separated as '|'.

Example if you pass parameter to function as `funsplit('SAGAR|INDIA|MUMBAI','|')`

it returns as

```
Item<Column Name>
SAGAR
INDIA
MUMBAI
```

I want it as

```
COLUMN 1   COLUMN2    COLUMN3
-----------------------------
SAGAR      INDIA      MUMBAI
```

Here is my function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[funSplit]
(
    @sInputList Varchar(8000), -- List of delimited items  
    @sDelimiter VarChar(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items  
)
Returns @List Table (item VarChar(8000))  
Begin  
 Declare @sItem VarChar(8000)  

 While CharIndex(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0  
  Begin  
   Select   
   @sItem=RTrim(LTrim(SubString(@sInputList,1,CharIndex(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),  
   @sInputList=RTrim(LTrim(SubString(@sInputList,CharIndex(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+Len(@sDelimiter),Len(@sInputList))))  

   If Len(@sItem) > 0  
    Insert Into @List Select @sItem  
 End  

 If Len(@sInputList) > 0  
  Insert Into @List Select @sInputList -- Put the last item in  

 Return  
End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will transpose your results.

```
select *
from
(
 SELECT Row_Number() over(order by Item) rn,  Item 
 from dbo.funsplit('SAGAR|INDIA|MUMBAI','|')
) src
PIVOT 
(Max(Item) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) p
```

If the order matters to you, you need to return that order from your function

If the columns are variable, then you can create the above with dynamic SQL and use `sp_executesql`

Comment: A typo - should be Row_Number()

Comment: Ordering is not proper.How shall i achieve it? The retrieved column list will be inserted into another table

Comment: Add an order column to the results of your function, and replace rownumber with that field

Answer (score 0):

Your @List variable should be a table with multiple columns like

```
DECLARE @List TABLE(col1 varchar(8000),col2 varchar(8000),col3 varchar(8000))
```

Therefore you need to know the number of stringparts in advance.

I know this is probably not what you need, but I am not sure, if you can do what you want any other way.

Hope it helps a bit